# Is it possible to change citrus environmental variables after assigning them a particular values

Tags: java, spring, citrus-framework

I have code like this

```
System.setProperty("citrus.xml.file.name.pattern", "/**/*test.xml");
```

I want to change the file name pattern after loading of context file and properties file is it possible through this code

```
    @Test @Parameters("context")
  @CitrusXmlTest()
 public void xmlTest(@Optional @CitrusResource TestContext context)
{
   ct=context.getApplicationContext();
    StandardEnvironment config=  (StandardEnvironment) ct.getEnvironment(); 
    System.out.println("111111111111"+config.getPropertySources());
    MutablePropertySources msr=config.getPropertySources(); 
    Map m=new HashMap();
    m.put("citrus.xml.file.name.pattern","/**/*xyz.xml");
    MapPropertySource mps=new MapPropertySource("systemProperties", m);
    msr.addFirst(mps);

}
```

after this test case i have a another test case like this

```
@CitrusXmlTest(packageScan= "com.citrus.testcases")
    public void CitrusTest() 
    {

    }
```

I am trying this code but citrus was not affecting the changed system properties
in the next test case it was executing the filenamepattern that was loaded the beginning is there any way to change system properties of citrus at runtime. Could any one please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Citrus will read the System property only once at startup. This is because this is a application wide environment setting that should not be changed after startup.

It seems that you want to load test cases based on some condition. I would rather use the TestNG test suite definitions where you can include and exclude tests based on packages, naming and other information given. You can read more information about that in the [testng-documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml).

In addition to that I would suggest to put those tests into different test groups so you can easily execute those tests in different test runs.